# ALM Rest API (C#) : Creation of Test Set

Tags: c#, rest, alm, hp-quality-center

I have successfully managed to sign-in/authenticate with my ALM instance using the Rest API, but I am now confused on what I should be doing to create a new test set.

```
private string CreateTestSetURL =  "{0}rest/domains/{1}/projects/{2}/test-sets";

// Parameters : 0 = Open Date, 1 = Description, 2 = parent, 3 = Name.
private const string TestSetsXML = "<Entity Type=\"test-set\">" +
    "<Fields>" +
        "<Field Name=\"status\"><Value>Open</Value></Field>" +
         "<Field Name=\"open-date\"><Value>{0}</Value></Field>" +
         "<Field Name=\"subtype-id\"><Value>hp.pc.test-set.performance</Value></Field>" +
         "<Field Name=\"description\"><Value>{1}</Value></Field>" +
         "<Field Name=\"parent-id\"><Value>{2}</Value></Field>" +
         "<Field Name=\"name\"><Value>{3}</Value></Field>" +
    "</Fields>" +
"</Entity>";

string requestURL = String.Format(TestSetsURL, baseRequestURL, qcSettings.QCDomain, qcSettings.QCProject);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestURL));

string xml = String.Format(TestSetsXML, "2015-12-17", "test please ignore", parent, "TestPleaseIgnore");
byte[] Requestbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

//request.
request.CookieContainer = authenticationCookieContainer;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = Requestbytes.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(Requestbytes, 0, Requestbytes.Length);
 requestStream.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

The result is this error :
"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Probably a couple of questions:

1. Should it be a post? - according to [documentation here](http://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.53/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST/test-sets.html%3FTocPath%3DResource%2520Reference%7CEntity%2520Resources%7CTest%2520Lab%7C_____7) it should be..
2. Is the format correct?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried Barneys suggestion, but I am still getting (400) Bad Request.

Question updated with changes.

Comment: The test set info should be part of your request body, not in the query string.

Comment: @Barney Do you mean it should be an XML you pass?

Comment: Have you initialized variable parent somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is set to what I believe correct..... Could it be something as simple as that??

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the server two important things (data = your_Xml and headers=for authorization) Then you should have no problem ;) Anyway is the error code 400 or 500? Usually 500 is a bad request / 400 is bad authorization

Can it be that your user have only read rights and it is not able to create?

Hope that you solved in the meanwhile your issue ;)